# Building R package using RStudio & roxygen2: Include a C function

Tags: c, r, package, rstudio, roxygen2

I built a R package using R and roxygen2. Eventually, everything worked out and I can build the package without any warnings and notes. However, I have some problems understanding why the integration of my C-function works.

The C-function is stored in the subfolder /src and, additionally, I included

```
# @useDynLib MyPackageName
```

into one of my R files. However, I actually do not really understand why this is working. Unfortunately, reading the R help 'Writing R extensions' didn't really help.

Comment: The blog post [Using Rcpp with RStudio](http://blog.rstudio.org/2012/11/29/rstudio-and-rcpp/) may have some additional helpful information.